# bigquery-create table not able to detect column header from CSV file(column headers in japanese lang.)

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, create-table

Using GCP console, I am trying to create table by uploading CSV file from local machine.

1st raw in CSV file contains column header and its in Japanese language.

Table is create successfully but title/header of column is displaying junk characters
(1---------------, 2------------------, 3-------------- etc)

Any idea how to read japanese column headers for creating table from CSV file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it UTF-8 encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you were able to read the file into BigQuery - however BigQuery doesn't support multibyte (UTF-8) characters for table names and column names.

This is a popular feature request in Japan. Please upvote and follow the following issue to keep up with updates:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65034056

Comment: Thanks for response Felipe Hoffa.